# Migrate TFS 2012 collections to an existing 2018 TFS environment

Tags: team-foundation-server

I can't seem to find any article(s) explaining how I can migrate existing TFS 2012 collections to an **existing** TFS 2018 environment.

Can I use this method - [Move a project collection using attach an detach](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/admin/move-project-collection)? Will detach and attach work on two different TFS collections?

Or, should I do this way - [Restore data to a different server or instance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2014/05/15/migrating-team-foundation-server-databases/)? I tried this, but somehow it's giving an error on TFSConfig RemapDBs. I cloned the current live TFS 2018 to a stage environment and was trying the steps mentioned. I am not sure if the error is because new environment has a different Config DB than the 2012 environment and the collection DB can't be remapped?

Please point me to an article you may know or explain steps if you did this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There used to be explicit warnings not to do "attach upgrades", but I'm not finding the articles with a quick search. The safe way from the current supported paths would be to do an in-place upgrade or migration upgrade of the 2012 (Update 4+ from the table https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/upgrade/get-started#previous-versions) to 2018 and then do the collection move from one 2018 server to the other.

Comment: I remember issues with attach/detach in older version of TFS: do not do it yourself, open a request support with MS to see if feasible.